# Disable Auto-Enumeration on Export to tex in Scrivener

Tags: scrivener, latex

I use Scrivener to write almost anything and recently got into writing Tex for University submissions and papers. Recently I hit the problem that most Exercise Sheet for my University are numbered like this:

```
Exercise 1
    a
    b
Exercise 2
    a
```

and the next sheet will start with Exercise 3 and so on. When I now use my typical workflow for Latex it will be exported like this:

```
1. Exercise 1
    1.1 a
    1.2 b
2. Exercise 2
    2.1 a
```

This isn't exactly nice. I know that this is due to the fact that scrivener seems to use `\chapter{}`and `\section{}`instead of `\chapter*{}`and `\section*{}`, but is there a nice, not so hacky-way to change this behavior? Maybe some preference I missed? I don't want to change all of the syntax of my tex before every compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert here but in exploring how to use LaTex and Scrivener I found this article on WordPress.com website created by a UK doctoral candidate - [Replacements for easy LaTeX inclusion in Scrivener](https://onhavingwords.wordpress.com/2013/10/06/replacements-latex-scrivener/#more-440).

Hopefully it will help.